# Mercury: SyntaxError: cannot return a value from a constructor

Tags: ruby-on-rails

Working on a fresh install of rails 3.2.8 and getting an error when compiling after adding [Mercury](https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury):

```
SyntaxError: cannot return a value from a constructor: "this.element" in class Button
 (in /home/*********/**************/vendor/bundle/ruby/1.8/bundler/gems/mercury-0c048033cd79/app/assets/javascripts/mercury/toolbar.button.js.coffee)
```

I've successfully installed Mercury using Rails 3.2.3, but haven't been able to figure why this wouldn't be working.

Any ideas?

```
source 'https://rubygems.org'

gem 'rails', '3.2.8'

# Bundle edge Rails instead:
# gem 'rails', :git => 'git://github.com/rails/rails.git'

gem 'mysql2'
gem 'bootstrap-sass'
gem 'simple_form'
gem 'json'
gem 'ckeditor'
gem 'mercury-rails', :git => 'https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury.git'


gem 'jquery-rails'
# gem 'jquery-ui-rails'

gem "paperclip", "~> 2.7"

# To use ActiveModel has_secure_password
gem 'bcrypt-ruby', '~> 3.0.0'

# Gems used only for assets and not required
# in production environments by default.
group :assets do
  gem 'sass-rails',   '~> 3.2.3'
  gem 'coffee-rails', '~> 3.2.1'

  # See https://github.com/sstephenson/execjs#readme for more supported runtimes
    gem 'therubyracer', '0.10.2', :platforms => :ruby
    gem 'libv8', '~> 3.3.10'
    gem 'execjs'
  gem 'uglifier', '>= 1.0.3'
end
```

Comment: fyi: https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury/issues/349

Answer (score 2, accepted):

https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury/issues/349

i guess you need to lock into coffeescript 1.4.0

this fixed my issue.

Comment: Thanks, my Google-Fu must be off; I couldn't find anything at all...  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Apparently, there is a fix, which is in the [github repo](https://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury), but not on rubygems, yet. If you don't want to downgrade coffee-script, just specify the repository in the Gemfile:

```
# Gemfile
# ...
gem 'mercury-rails', git: 'git://github.com/jejacks0n/mercury'
```

and run `bundle update mercury-rails`, afterwards. This fixed this problem for me without the need to downgrade coffee-script.

Answer (score 0):

Here's what you actually need to type into your gemfile:

```
gem 'coffee-script-source', '1.4.0'
```